# Проверка каждого значения массива со всеми значениями данного массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, foreach

```
var arr = ['qwe', 'qew', 'one']
```

Как проверить буквы каждого значения со всеми буквами из других значений? Если все буквы совпадают, значит пропустить, если хотя бы одна буква уникальная - записать в новый массив.

0 и 1 не пройдут, т.к. они одинаковы, а вот 2 пройдет, таких значений больше нет.

У меня проблема заключается в том, чтобы взять каждое значение, разбить на буквы и проверить эти буквы с такими же разбитыми буквами из других значений.

Выходит только разбить все буквы из массива и записать их в другой

```
    var arr = ['qwe', 'qew', 'one']
    var arrSplit = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for(var a = 0; a < arr[i].length; a++){
            arrSplit.push(arr[i][a])
        }
    }
    console.log(arrSplit)
```

Пробовал через forEach, но не вышло так сделать, но думаю в нем и заключается ответ

Comment: Ответ заключается в использовании корректного (а желательно и оптимального) алгоритма и в минимальных знаниях JavaScript-a.

Comment: Строки `qweq` и `qwe` являются уникальными, и обе остаются? А в случае `qwe` и `qew` обе удаляются?

Comment: @Regent да, правильно

Comment: Может сумму кодов символов посчитать , а потом уже чиселки сравнивать?

Comment: Сумму невариант.  Ведь для примера на простых числах: 1+2+3 =6, и 2+2+2 = 6. Тоесть будут коллизии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напишем функцию для подсчета хэша строки в виде символов этой строки упорядоченных по порядку.

```
function getHash(value) {
  return value.split('').sort().join('')
}
```

Подсчитаем хэши всех строк в массиве

```
var hashArr = arr.map(function(value) {
  return getHash(value)
});
```

Подсчитаем количество повторений для каждого хэша

```
var counts = hashArr.reduce(function(c, hash) {
  c[hash] = (c[hash] || 0) + 1;
  return c;
}, {});
```

Выберем только те хэши, которые имеют повторения

```
var duplicates = Object.keys(counts).filter(function(item) {
  return counts[item] > 1;
});
```

И наконец отфильтруем исходный массив по совпадению хэша элемента

```
var result = arr.filter(function(value) {
  return duplicates.indexOf(getHash(value)) === -1;
});
```

---

Полный код примера:

```js
var arr = ['qwe', 'qew', 'one', 'ewq', 'weqr']

function getHash(value) {
  return value.split('').sort().join('')
}

var hashArr = arr.map(function(value) {
  return getHash(value)
});

var counts = hashArr.reduce(function(c, hash) {
  c[hash] = (c[hash] || 0) + 1;
  return c;
}, {});

var duplicates = Object.keys(counts).filter(function(item) {
  return counts[item] > 1;
});

var result = arr.filter(function(value) {
  return duplicates.indexOf(getHash(value)) === -1;
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое